# Why can't I log in on this website using requests?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a web scraper using Python. The website has a login form though and I've been trying to log in for a few days with no results. The code looks like this:

```
session_requests = requests.Session()
r = session_requests.get(login_url, headers=dict(referer=login_url))
print(r.content)
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath('//input[@name="_csrf_token"]/@value')))[0]
payload = {"_csrf_token": authenticity_token, "_username": "-username-", "_password": "-password-",}
r = session_requests.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=dict(referer=login_url))
print(r.content)
```

You can see I print out `r.content` both before and after posting to the login page, and in theory I should get different outputs (because the second one should be the content of the actual web page after the login), but unfortunately I get the exact same output.
Here's a screenshot of what the login page requires to log in:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evGNf.png)
Also, I know for sure that the _csrf_token is correct because I have tested it a few times, so no doubts about that part.
Another thing that might be useful: I don't think I really need to include the headers because the outputs are exactly the same with or without them (I include them just because). Thanks in advance.

Edit: the URL is https://nuvola.madisoft.it/login

Here's some more useful stuff:
[image]
[image]

Comment: it may check other  elements - ie. headers. Better show url for this page. Showing only coden can be useless.

Comment: Without any other details. The only thing that might cause this is a missing header. Trying adding a `user-agent` header.

Comment: Just added the URL of the login page

Comment: Have you tried switching to selenium?

Comment: At a glance I could spot that the log-in url and the referer should be different whereas you used the same url in both the places.

Comment: @cricket_007 just tried selenium. it's pretty cool but since my ultimate goal is to move this code to an app, i don't think selenium is really the best move. thanks anyways.

Comment: @SIM just fixed it and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Try using those cookies in the headers first. However, if you still doesn't get the desired response, use the exact headers being sent with the post requests what you can see in chrome dev tools.

Comment: @SIM can i post a picture of chrome dev tools? i think that'll make it easier for you to explain what you mean :)

Comment: Copy the code available in this [link](https://filebin.net/8tryqha0uofedzwt) and use the same. Make sure to replace the cookie that I've taken from my end.

Comment: @SIM wow thanks a lot! so now i just have to find a way to get the cookie everytime?

Comment: You can grab the cookie from get requests headers like `cookie = r.headers['set-cookie'].split(" ")[0]` and reuse the same in post requests automatically to see if it works. Btw, did the script work out?